# Ember render all templates in folder

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am using Ember and Bootstrap and I want to create the folder `/templates/modals/` with a seperate .hbs file for each modal. Currently at the end of my application.hbs I have a list of all the modals

```
{{render 'modals/harry'}}
{{render 'modals/potter'}}
{{render 'modals/you'}}
{{render 'modals/are'}}
{{render 'modals/a'}}
{{render 'modals/wizard'}}
```

Is there a way to render all the files in a folder?

Comment: Your example should work, your problem could be that your template name is not assigned correctly to Ember.TEMPLATES instance. An example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jilep/1/edit. Or Do you mean to render all files using an each helper iterating the templates folder?

Comment: What I am currently doing works fine for me but I am just being lazy and not wanting to have to remember to copy and past {{render 'modals/myModal'}} every time. It would be great if I could do it automatically.

Comment: You cannot do that because the render helper does not accepts a quoteless parameter https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-routing/lib/helpers/render.js#L110

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was already using [Grunt Ember Templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) and ended up putting in this JavaScript

```
Ember.TEMPLATES.modals = function(context, options) {
    for (var template in Ember.TEMPLATES) {
        if (/^modals[\/\\][a-z0-9-]*/i.test(template)) {
            Ember.TEMPLATES[template](context, options);
        }
    }
};
```

and having `{{render 'modals'}}` in my application.hbs

Answer (score 1):

Natively, theres no way to do that.

But check out Ember CLI ( http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/).